System.InvalidOperationException: Could not create getter for System.Threading.ExecutionContext& Context
I have Stocks and AppUsers tables and Portfolios table which is the many-to-many relations between them. I want to get the data of portfolios, but encounter a problem in my API. It says:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error getting value from 'Context' on 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1+AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[api.Models.Stock],API.Repositories.Concrete.PortfolioRepository+<GetUserPortfolio>d__2]'.
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not create getter for System.Threading.ExecutionContext& Context. ByRef return values are not supported.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ReflectionDelegateFactory.CreateGet[T](MemberInfo memberInfo)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ExpressionValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ExpressionValueProvider.GetValue(Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.CalculatePropertyValues(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContainerContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonProperty property, JsonContract& memberContract, Object& memberValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

My Controller:
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserPortfolio()
{
    var username = User.GetUsername();
    var appUser = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
    var userPortfolio = portfolioReposiotry.GetUserPortfolio(appUser);
    return Ok(userPortfolio);
}


My repo:
public class PortfolioRepository : IPortfolioRepository
{
    private readonly AppDbContext context;

    public PortfolioRepository(AppDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public async Task<List<Stock>> GetUserPortfolio(AppUser user)
    {
        var val = context.Portfolios.Where(u => u.AppUserId == user.Id)
            .Select(stock => new Stock
            {
                Id = stock.StockId,
                Symbol = stock.Stock.Symbol,
                CompanyName = stock.Stock.CompanyName,
                Purchase = stock.Stock.Purchase,
                LastDiv = stock.Stock.LastDiv,
                Industry = stock.Stock.Industry,
                MarketCap = stock.Stock.MarketCap
            });
        return await val.ToListAsync();
    }
}

I don't know if anything else is needed. If so, please let me know
I didn't try any solutions as I have no idea what is going on.

In case anybody has this problem, it could be that you forgot to use await


System.InvalidOperationException: Could not create getter for
System.Threading.ExecutionContext& Context
I don't know if anything else is needed. If so, please let me know
I didn't try any solutions as I have no idea what is going on.

Based on your scenario and description the error you are getting could have couple of reasons.
First of all, ensure that the Stock model doesn't contain any properties that could cause serialization issues. It's possible that there's a property named 'Context' in the Stock model or one of its related classes.
In addition, GetUserPortfolio method is asynchronous, and you're awaiting its result properly. However, you haven't maintained the asynchronous  chain while calling GetUserPortfolio method in controller just right after appUser.
So in order fix that you should refactor your code as following:
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserPortfolio()
{
    var username = User.GetUsername();
    var appUser = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
    var userPortfolio = await  portfolioReposiotry.GetUserPortfolio(appUser);
    return Ok(userPortfolio);
}

Note: Make sure User.GetUsername() also maintain the same asynchronous chain.
